# Origin of a custom of deceased attending their own wakes?

Tags: inspiration, amra-thetys-series

In the first book of the Amra Thetys series a charming local custom is described in which the deceased attends his own funeral banquet:

> I was a little late. They’d already had the ceremonial meal and were cleaning up from that. Which was fine; as much as I cared for Corbin, he wasn’t smelling like a flower, and despite the careful makeup he looked like what he was- a corpse propped up in a comfy chair at the head of the funerary table. It reminded me of nothing so much as some sort of gruesome child’s tea party, but like I said, I’m not from Lucernis.
>    <sub>The Thief Who Pulled on Trouble's Braids - Chapter 16</sub>

What was the inspiration for this particular custom? Does it come from the author's imagination entirely or maybe it's based on historical or anthropological records of similar traditions?